# What is the title (position) of a person who finds deals with other companies?

Tags: job-description, title, position

We currently have a small Software company. We have a couple apps, but we also provide software outsourcing. We want to create (a) position(s) for someone who seeks and arranges outsourcing deals with other companies by any means possible. Is there a title specific to this role? Or is this a kind of marketing/selling? If there exists one, is there a hierarchy (Senior/Junior etc) for that role?

Comment: The first thing that comes into my mind would a _key account manager_. Though the definition probably varies from country to country.

Comment: "sales".  would be the usual term

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually some variation on 'Account Manager' once there is a contract.

Prior to that it's marketing.

With software companies I have seen CTO's (Chief Technical Officer) who do the negotiating and liaison with outside companies.

Answer (score 0):

You want a sales person - some might give it specific titles such as "Business Development Executive" or similar but it means the same thing in this context. You want a sales person.

> is there a hierarchy (Senior/Junior etc) for that role?

Only if you create one.